# SQL Aggregate Sum to Only Net Out Negative Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to roll up product values based on dates. The example below starts out with 20,000, adds 5,000, and then subtracts 7,000. The result should be eating through the entire 5,000 and then into the prior positive row. This would remove the 5,000 row.

I think this would be as simple as doing a sum window function ordered by date descending. However, as you can see below, I want to stop summing at any row that remains positive and then move to the next.

I cannot figure out the logic in SQL to make this work. In my head, it should be:

```
SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Product, (positive valued rows) ORDER BY Date DESC)
```

But there could be multiple positive valued rows in a row where a negative valued row could eat through all of them, or there could be multiple negative values in a row.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827619/a-rollup-query-with-some-logical-netting-using-oracle-sql) seemed promising, but I don't think the logic would work for if a negative value would be larger than the positive value.

HAVE:

```
+------------+----------------+-------+
|    Date    |    Product     | Value |
+------------+----------------+-------+
| 01/13/2015 | Prod1          | 20000 |
| 08/13/2015 | Prod1Addition1 |  5000 |
| 12/13/2015 | Prod1Removal   | -7000 |
| 02/13/2016 | Prod1Addition2 |  2000 |
| 03/13/2016 | Prod1Addition3 |  1000 |
| 04/13/2016 | Prod1Removal   | -1500 |
+------------+----------------+-------+
```

WANT:

```
+------------+----------------+-------+
|    Date    |    Product     | Value |
+------------+----------------+-------+
| 01/13/2015 | Prod1          | 18000 |
| 02/13/2016 | Prod1Addition2 |  1500 |
+------------+----------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can only think of a recursive cte solution

```
; with 
cte as
(
    select  Date, Product, Value, rn = row_number() over (order by Date)
    from    yourtable
),
rcte as
(
    select  Date, Product, Value, rn, grp = 1
    from    cte 
    where   rn  = 1
    union all
    select  Date    = case when r.Value < 0 then c.Date else r.Date end, 
        Product = case when r.Value < 0 then c.Product else r.Product end, 
        c.Value, 
        c.rn, 
        grp = case when r.Value < 0 then r.grp + 1 else r.grp end
    from    rcte r
        inner join cte c    on  r.rn    = c.rn - 1
)
select  Date, Product, Value = sum(Value)
from    rcte
group by Date, Product, grp     
order by Date
```

Comment: I was afraid of a recursive CTE due to performance concerns. Would this be something to do in an ETL process before even querying the data?

Comment: regardless of the performance issue, this is worth one vote from me. For the OP, you can try using some solution with CURSOR if you want a better performance. I'm sure you don't have many choices to solve this, it's some kind of a tough problem. One possible solution (which is easy and also performs best) is try using some .NET custom function, you create that function in some .NET assembly, use it in your query. The .NET function allows you to use some static variable, so you can easily define it to return the key for grouping.

Comment: @KingKing Do you have any links to documentation and examples that could show me what you're referring to? I agree Squirrel's's response is very relevant to the problem.

Comment: @houstonwp you can read this page carefully (there is a Note section there and a simple example of a CLR user-defined function) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 About returning the grouping key, the function should receive just 1 argument (passed-in with `Value`), you need to declare a static variable in C# code, outside the function. In the function you just check the passed-in argument, if it's less than `0`, just increase the static variable by 1 after returning that static variable.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you want this:

```
select Date,
       Product,
       Sum(Value) As Value
  From TABLE_NAME
 Group By Date, Product
 Order by Date, Product;
```

thats correct?

Comment: No, this is grouping by dates, and the dates vary for each addition and removal.